# How to remove text file selectively in linux home directory

Tags: terminal

The title pretty much explains what I want to accomplish. I was able to accomplish half the task which was to summarise all the files which were of type ASCII in my Home directory but not able to accomplish the other half which was to remove those files.

```
mohit@dell3568:~$ ls | xargs -n 1 -I{} file {} | grep ASCII | cut -f1 -d ":" | xargs -n 1 -I{} rm -i {}
rm: remove regular file 'a'? rm: remove regular file 'adfasdf'? rm: remove regular file 'asdf'? rm: remove regular file 'auto-remove-NON_REMOVED'? rm: remove regular file 'BIGGEST_PACKAGE'? rm: remove write-protected regular file 'config_DOT_dpkg-new.bak'? rm: remove regular file 'CutCommandInLinuxPrac'? rm: remove regular file 'duplicateTorrentFilesInTorrentTwoFolderUnderTheCompleteWebDevCourse.txt'? rm: remove regular file 'etc_mono_config.bak'? rm: remove regular file 'FileForGrepPrac'? rm: remove regular file 'FolderView.qml.bak---Copied_as_I__made_changes_----590and607LinesAreChanged.bak'? rm: remove regular file 'GRUB_EaSy_22'?
```

I wasn't able to delete the files as it was not giving the option to select 'yes' or 'no'. Thanks for any help.

```
rm: remove regular file 'headTestFileDelMeLater'? 
rm: remove regular file 'historyOUT.txt'? 
rm: remove regular file 'JavaForLogRead.java'? 
rm: remove regular file 'online-terminal-PS1'? 
rm: remove regular file 'packagesSize.txt'? 
rm: remove regular file 'TableExample'? 
rm: remove regular file 'TankGame'? 
rm: remove regular file 'VeryImpUSEFULcommandsLINUX'? 
rm: remove regular file 'Xresources'?
```

Comment: Please check if you have appropriate rights to delete

Comment: Yes, I'm in the sudoers. The problem is that it doesn't pause for my input 'y' or 'n' instead it completes the entire execution cycle without waiting for my input.